# Can Multiple Vagrant VMs communicate by VM hostname?

Tags: networking, vagrant

I am managing multiple VMs with Vagrant. Networks are configured as private, ip addresses have been set and hostnames are assigned. As shown in the Vagrantfile below.

The VMs can communicate with each other via the IP address, but I would like to know how to allow VMs to communicate using their assigned hostname. I.e. How to make `ping comtest2` work from `comtest1`?

Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define "comtest1" do |comtest1|
    comtest1.vm.box = "precise32"
    comtest1.vm.hostname = "comtest1"
    comtest1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.21"
  end

  config.vm.define "comtest2" do |comtest2|
    comtest2.vm.box = "precise32"
    comtest2.vm.hostname = "comtest2"
    comtest2.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.22"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Cheat the dns resolution with https://github.com/adrienthebo/vagrant-hosts ?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a more legit way instead of using a plugin and "cheating"?

I wonder whether this limitation comes from the VM provider or Vagrant.

Comment: The [@neutrinus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30780347/4396730) answer is the simplest approach

Answer (score 16):

You can use Zeroconf. It broadcasts the host name  in network and makes it available to the other hosts on the local network. That way you can access your hosts using test1.local, test2.local, etc.

Just install `avahi-daemon` and `libnss-mdns`!

### Example

`Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
  
  config.vm.define "vm1" do |machine|
    machine.vm.hostname = "vm1"
    machine.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
  end

  config.vm.define "vm2" do |machine|
    machine.vm.hostname = "vm2"
    machine.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
  end
  
  # allow guests to reach each other by hostname
  config.vm.provision "allow_guest_host_resolution",
    type: "shell",
    inline: <<-SHELL
      apt update
      apt install -y avahi-daemon libnss-mdns
    SHELL
    
end
```

### Test

```
$ vagrant up
...
$ vagrant ssh vm1 -- ping -c 1 vm2.local
PING vm2.local (172.28.128.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.28.128.8 (172.28.128.8): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.333 ms

$ vagrant ssh vm2 -- ping -c 1 vm1.local
PING vm1.local (172.28.128.7) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.28.128.7 (172.28.128.7): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.254 ms
```

Comment: This seems to work and looks like the easiest way to communicate.

Comment: What's the rest of the `Vagrantfile` look like if this is used? (Not the provisioning of those packages, but the networking, machine naming, etc.)

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out and added a functioning example.

Comment: While in principal this seems like a great idea your actual results may vary. mDNS doesn't work for apps that perform true NS resolution, which is often the case for things written in Go. I ran into this specifically while trying to setup Prometheus, but found instances of the same issue with Docker.  (see: https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/3297)

Answer (score 5):

It isn't the most elegant solution in the world but it is very simple, how about something like:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define "comtest1" do |comtest1|
    comtest1.vm.box = "precise32"
    comtest1.vm.hostname = "comtest1"
    comtest1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.21"
    comtest1.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
       sed -i '$ a 192.168.10.22 comtest2' /etc/hosts           
    SHELL
  end

  config.vm.define "comtest2" do |comtest2|
    comtest2.vm.box = "precise32"
    comtest2.vm.hostname = "comtest2"
    comtest2.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.22"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

If the host resolves DNS correctly, then you can configure Virtualbox to use the host as the DNS resolver.

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
end
```

See https://serverfault.com/a/506206/250071

---

We use a local Ansible task to automatically add the provisioned box to the host `/etc/hosts` file. It is a little awkward, but has been very robust.

```
- setup:
  gather_subset: [network]
- name: Add host mapping to local /etc/hosts
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/hosts regexp=".+{{ vm.hostname }}$" line="{{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses|sort|last }} {{ vm.hostname }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [landrush on Github](https://github.com/phinze/landrush). 
It will setup a DNS for your vagrant private network.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This appears to be working only for Linux hosts. Seems to have a pre-req for `iptables`.